# Error occured processing XML on spring webflow-config

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

I get this error message when adding my xml file as bean configuration :

> Error occured processing
>   '/j2eeapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/webflow-config.xml'

My xml file (webflow-config.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
           xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">

        <bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener">
                <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
                <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

        <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
                <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
                        <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener" />
                        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
                        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener"/>
                </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        </webflow:flow-executor>                        

        <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
                <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
        </webflow:flow-registry>

        <faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

        <faces:resources />

        <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
                <property name="order" value="1"/>
                <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
                <property name="defaultHandler">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
                </property>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
                <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

  </beans>
```

Exception stack trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfRuntimeInformation   at
>   org.springframework.faces.config.ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:406)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:390)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:449)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The error is showb at the line of :

```
>  <faces:resources/>
```

with this message : `Could not initialise class org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfRuntimeInformation`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: make sure it has all the classes imported here in classpath https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow/blob/master/spring-faces/src/main/java/org/springframework/faces/webflow/JsfRuntimeInformation.java

Comment: I m sorry, i didn't understand you, could you be more specific?

Comment: all the classes that this class needs (check all import statements) are present in your classpath as well ?

Comment: If you are working with Maven, share the pom.xml configuration specially the <dependencies>, seems one is missing or perhaps there is a conflict of versions.